# how to discretize a dataframe based on the whole matrix with NAs in each row

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data matrix like the following dataframe of the following shape (but with more columns):
df:=

```
 V1       V2       V3       V4       V5
1 c0   0.0000   1.0000   2.0000   3.0000
2 c1   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   NA
3 c2   0.0000   0.0000   NA       NA
4 c3 125.0605 120.8402 125.0950   124.8971
5 c4   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   163.4609
```

I want to discretise these numeric values in say 10 bins where the max of the bin is the `max(df, na.rm=T)` and min of the bin is `min(df, na.rm = T)`.

What I have now is the following code, but I get stuck on how to replace these numeric values with bin number.

```
min_bin = min(df, na.rm = T)
max_bin = max(df, na.rm = T)
bin_range = seq(from = min_bin, to = max_bin, by = ceil(max_bin/10))
bin_range = cbind(bin_range, max_bin)
# [1]  0  17  34  51  68  85 102 119 136 153  163.5
```

and the desired output is the following:

```
  V1  V2       V3       V4       V5
1 c0   1        1        1        1
2 c1   1        1        1        NA
3 c2   1        1        NA       NA
4 c3   8        8        8        8
5 c4   1        1        1        10
```

I can think of a for loop that can do the job for me, but I am really looking something more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the numeric columns, `unlist` them and use `cut` specifying number of bins you want to divde the data into.

```
df[-1] <- cut(unlist(df[-1]), 10, labels = FALSE)
df
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1 c0  1  1  1  1
#2 c1  1  1  1 NA
#3 c2  1  1 NA NA
#4 c3  8  8  8  8
#5 c4  1  1  1 10
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:5, .Label = c("c0", "c1", "c2", 
"c3", "c4"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(0, 0, 0, 125.0605, 0), 
V3 = c(1, 0, 0, 120.8402, 0), V4 = c(2, 0, NA, 125.095, 0
), V5 = c(3, NA, NA, 124.8971, 163.4609)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```